# What is the name of this Final Fantasy Dimensions skill? (Spoilers)

Tags: final-fantasy-dimensions

In Final Fantasy Dimensions, what is the name of the special skill Jinnai uses against Tobikage?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the skill had the same name as their hometown: Hagakure